# MongoDB sum values in document

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm making an application with MongoDB and C#. I use the MongoDB driver.

```
{
     _id: ObjectId("5099803df3f4948bd2f98391"),
     Title: "Test",
     Rating: {
          1234 : 4.0,
          4689 : 2.5,
          1987 : 1.5
     }
}
```

Now I want to get the average rating. So (4.0+2.5+1.5) / 3.
But how do I do this with MongoDB and the C# driver.
I'm trying to unwind and then count. But it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$objectToArray` (from mongo version 3.4.4) to convert object to array and calculate `$avg`

```
db.t71.aggregate([
    {$addFields : {data : {$objectToArray : "$Rating"}}}, 
    {$addFields : {avg : {$avg : "$data.v"}}}
]).pretty()
```

aggregation

```
> db.t71.aggregate([{$addFields : {data : {$objectToArray : "$Rating"}}}, {$addFields : {avg : {$avg : "$data.v"}}}]).pretty()
{
        "_id" : 1,
        "Title" : "Test",
        "Rating" : {
                "1234" : 4,
                "1987" : 1.5,
                "4689" : 2.5
        },
        "data" : [
                {
                        "k" : "1234",
                        "v" : 4
                },
                {
                        "k" : "1987",
                        "v" : 1.5
                },
                {
                        "k" : "4689",
                        "v" : 2.5
                }
        ],
        "avg" : 2.6666666666666665
}
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding how to do this in C# with the MongodB driver. Because AddFields isn't available in C#

Comment: what version of mongo DB and C# driver are you using?

Comment: MongoDB driver version is 2.7.2

Comment: can you try `$project` instead of `$addFields`

Comment: Yes, project is available

Comment: This code may not work with the C# mongo driver